# Sharepoint Online Add Link To Form in Document Set Content Type

Tags: document, document-set

I have a document library and added a Document Set Content type. The Content Type is configure to add important files automatically upon creation of a new Doc Set.
Now I am after adding Links to a set of individual EForms by PowerApps or SP Forms. 
Say I have 3 Links as well per Doc Set.
Can somebody point me to the proper method as cannot find the proper way yet. I can add manually a link in Document Set from New menu.
I have tried adding a file with name report.url but did not work either.
[image]
Tks

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Document Set direclty from Power Apps Form is not possible as of today. You need to use Power Automate.

I have managed to set the Link To my eforms as URL shortcut from the Document Settings by adding a new Document Content TYpe and added myForm.url file.The file contents is:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://emoffice365.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Lists/MyFormName/NewForm.aspx
```